# Typegoose Alias with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, graphql, typegoose

I had a question regarding Aliases. Is it possible to do an alias on a a variable inside an embedded object? I understand I can do a virtual get to achieve this as well, however, graphql does not see the variable when doing this approach. If you have a way to make the virtual work please let me know! For example I was thinking something along the lines as follows?:

```
export class Embedded {
    @prop({nullable: false}, alias: "Parent.testName")
    name: string; // Variable I want to get
}

export class Parent {
    @prop({nullable: false})
    ObjectWithName: Embedded;

    testName: string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*ref: [typegoose/typegoose#305](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/305)*

this is not possible without an virtual getter, [here is the documentation](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/prop/#alias) of how to use the mongoose provided alias

Comment: thank you for letting me know! I am trying to connect this to graphql and unfortunately, virtual getters return null. Is it possible to use virtual getters with graphql?

Comment: sorry, i dont know - i never used graphql | type-graphql